# wordpress echo slug from array into a table cell with count

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

What I want is to got through the array of slug names and echo the slug count.
The post type is 'movies' & taxonomy 'genre'. I had working code before but not within a cell of a table.

```
<table width="100%">

<?php 

$genre_array = array( "action", "adventure", "animation", "biography", "comedy", "crime", "documentary", "drama", "family", "fantasy", "film-Noir", "history", "horror", "music", "musical", "mystery", "romance", "sci-Fi", "sport", "thriller", "war", "western" );

for ($x = 0; $x<21; $x++) { ?>

<tr border-bottom: 1px thick #fff;>

<td class="movie_genre" style="width: 120px;">

<?php echo $genre_array[$x]; ?>

</td>

<td class="movie_genre" style="width: 40px; color: #ddd;">
                                -
</td>

<td class="movie_genre">

<?php

$movie_genre = $genre_array[$x];

echo $movie_genre->count;

?>

</td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Hope help is near
Steven

Comment: use `get_term_by` function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: So the format of that is: <?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?> so I should add get_term_by( $slug, 'count', 'genre' ) ?

Comment: you should define a variable for example : `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, 'genre' );` then you can get the count with `echo $term->count;`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick

Comment: My pleasure, hope it'd helped :)